# How to thumbnail image for youtube video on a webpage with play button

Tags: youtube, html

How to thumbnail image for youtube video on a webpage with play button? See example, http://ethicsunwrapped.utexas.edu/video/introduction-to-behavioral-ethics

The link should go to

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

1. put that thumbnail image to your site with a link

   < div id="wrapper">< a id='test_id'>< img>< /a>< /div>
2. create some jquery code, to change the img with the video on click

   $( "#test_id" ).click(function() {

   ```
     $("#wrapper").html("youtube-code");
   ```

   });

finish